# create temp table in sqlite function

Tags: function, temp-tables, sqlitestudio

I have function in sqlite and I want to use temp table for declaring variables in this function. when I use this query out of function, it works, but use it inside function, returns null value.

problem is cause of using temp table in function.
what shold I do?

this is the code:

```
create temp table if not exists tmp(output varchar);

delete from tmp;
insert into tmp(output) values(@arg);

select output from tmp;
```

Comment: I see no function. Show the actual code.

Comment: this is the body of function. just define a function and call function with @arg argument and see what it returns

Comment: SQLite has no functions.

Comment: but in sqlite studio I created and used it. in here I cant call it outside of sqlite studio. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLiteStudio documentation](http://wiki.sqlitestudio.pl/index.php/User_Manual#Custom_SQL_functions) says:

> Custom SQL functions created in SQLiteStudio exist only in context of SQLiteStudio. [...]
>   If you want to use some function in your own application, you have to register that function in SQLite from your application.